# Building up a binary representation in C

Tags: c, binary

As the title says. I've looked at some of the related questions, but they aren't doing it the same way I am. Here is the code snippet:

```
int convert(int in, unsigned int newBase, char result[]){
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 32; ++i){
        if (in % newBase == 0)
            result[i] = '0';
        else
            result[i] = '1';
        in = in / newBase;
        ++i;
    }
    result[31] = "\0";
    return 1;
}
```

`result[]` is guaranteed by the driver file to be of size 32. As an example, if I call `convert(1275, 2, result[0]);`, it should build up the binary representation (backwards, but that's not a problem for now) 11011111001. It does this, but interspersed with all of the binary digits is a capital I with an accent on it. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you really calling `convert(1275, 2, result[0]);` ?

Comment: `++i;` at inside loop is superfluous

Comment: Yes... I'm new to C (more familiar with C++). I just changed it to `convert(1275, 2 result);` and there was no change.
BLUEPIXY, that's it. I'd originally had a while loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To hold 32 binary digits as a string, `result` needs to be 33 bytes, and the null goes at `result[32]` (the 33rd char) and not `result[31]`.

Also, the null as a char constant should use single quotes, not double quotes... so change:

```
result[31] = "\0";
```

to:

```
result[32] = '\0';
```

...and make sure `result` has room for at least 33 chars.  The weird characters you're seeing could be the result of trying to write the address of the string literal 
"\0" into `result`.

Comment: Both of your points are great; I didn't put the 0-starting index and the extra space needed for the null character together.